# Session integration on CodeIgniter and KCFinder

Tags: codeigniter, session

i would like to use the codeigniter session to enable kcfinder only for logged in users.

in my login controller i set the session like

```
 $sesData = array(
          'userId'  => $this->input->post('username',true),
           .....
           'KCFINDER' => Array('disabled' => FALSE)
 );
```

in the kcfinder config.php i have the session var as default

```
'_sessionVar' => &$_SESSION['KCFINDER'],
```

But i still can't access the finder (through ckeditor) i get "You don't have permission to browse server".

In config.php of kcfinder if i turn this

```
'disabled' => true,
```

to

```
'disabled' => false,
```

kcfinder works great but it has public access.

Comment: Do you have CI to use native file sessions or database sessions?

Comment: native file session. The session works great.

Answer (score 3):

i found a temporary solution by setting the kcfinder session as

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['KCFINDER'] = array(); 
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled'] = false;
```

but i still looking for a codeigniter solution

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access CI sessions outside CI. But if you use this library you can use CI session syntax and access the session info outside CI as well.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session

Cheers,

Bart